# Creating a WM_USER handler with MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Though I've had plenty of software experience I've not done a great deal of Windows programming. I'm trying to post a WM_USER message from a thread so that it gets picked up in the main UI thread but I'm having some trouble. This is in C++ using VS2010 and MFC.

I've created a message map thus,

```
#define WM_MYMSG (WM_USER + 77)
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyApp, CWinApp)
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_MYMSG, DoSomething)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Declared the handler function as follows,

```
afx_msg LRESULT DoSomething(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

And written the function body as,

```
LRESULT CMyApp::DoSomething( WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) 
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

    CallSomeFunction();
    return 0L;
}
```

As far as I can see this is all in line with what MSDN says as stated here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/k35k2bfs(v=vs.100).aspx

However I'm getting an

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'LRESULT (__cdecl CMyApp::*)(WPARAM,LPARAM)' to 'LRESULT (__cdecl CWnd::* )(WPARAM,LPARAM)'
```

relating to the line

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_AVATAR_SCALE_MSG, DoSomething)
```

Can anyone let me know what the problem is?

Thanks for reading.

Paul

Comment: Don't. `WM_USER` is the start of a range of identifiers reserved for private _window classes_ (In the MS Windows sense of the word). Since your `CMyApp` isn't `CWnd`-derived, it does not have a window class, and should not use the reserved `WM_USER` range. You're probably looking for `WM_APP`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMyApp inherits from CWinApp, which inherits from CWinThread. CWinThread user-defined messages take a special macro in their message map for what you want to do:

Change this:

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_AVATAR_SCALE_MSG, DoSomething)
```

To this:

```
ON_THREAD_MESSAGE(WM_AVATAR_SCALE_MSG, DoSomething)
```

Assuming `DoSomething()` is a member of your `CMyApp` class.

See the documentation on [`ON_THREAD_MESSAGE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cy89e70%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks again, but simply changing to use ON_THREAD_MESSAGE gives the same error. I'm assuming the signature of the handler needs to change but the documentation doesn't specify what I should use.

Comment: @PaulN The format had been `LRESULT CWinApp::DoSomething(WPARAM, LPARAM)`, and the messages should be `WM_APP`+n based. I've seen `void CWinApp::MemberFn(WPARAM,LPARAM)` as well, so it'd take some check to to know for sure. EDIT: I think it is the latter. If you're still getting the identical error message make sure the old one is taken *out* of the map and post the update in an addendum to your question. Something else looks like its not quite lined up right.

Comment: @PaulN I just checked, your message function should be prototyped as `afx_msg void DoSomething(WPARAM, LPARAM)` in the `CMyApp` class declaration. Also, `WM_APP+n` should be your basis for your message; don't forget that (or register a custom message id if you're feeling particularly randy).

Comment: Thank you again, that did the trick. Also, and this is just an observation, why is it that if I call PostThreadMessage with 4 arguments, as documented it complains that it doesn't take 4 arguments, whereas 3 works fine!

Comment: @PaulN: PostThreadMessage definitely takes 4 arguments. You may want to ask that as a separate question, with its own SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

THe problem is that the message map expects a function on a CWnd, whereas your class clearly is not a CWnd, either by virtue of actually being such or inheriting from CWnd.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually derived from CWinApp. Can you advise on how to set up a WM_USER for a class derived from that?

Answer (score -1):

The function expects you to pass a method of CWnd that takes a WPARAM and an LPARAM, but you're passing in a function of CMyApp.

Make the CMyApp class extend off of the CWnd class:

```
class CMyApp : public CWnd {
    // members here
};
```

**edit**

If this isn't possible, then you're going to have to find a way to pass in a function of CWnd or any other function of a class that extends off of CWnd with the right parameters and return type.

Comment: Um. no. Other way around. Use the correct message macro, don't reroot CMyApp.